# Array.reduce() stacking numbers rather than summing them?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to reduce an array of numbers into the sum of all the numbers combined. At the moment I'm using `Array.reduce` to try and achieve this, but what I'm finding is that this function only stacks the array's values to create one massive number rather than summing them all together.

```
// Function used to get the sum of all numbers in array

function getSum(total, num){
    return total + num; 

// Reduce Var 

var easternSum = scoreEastern.reduce(getSum);

// Dynamic array based on user input

var scoreEastern = dataSet
                    .filter(scoreEastern => scoreEastern.Course === 'eastern')
                    .map(({Score}) => Score);

// Empty array that scoreEastern var is assigned to

var dataSet = [];
```

Because my array is dynamic, it's based on what the user inputs into a form, there's no set array. But let's say the array is:

```
var scoreEastern = [10, 20, 30]
```

The reduce var `easternSum` will result in the number 102,030. What I want is 60.

Comment: `Score` property is probably a string. Try with `.map(({ Score }) => +Score)`

Comment: @adiga Thanks, that did it. Apologies for posting the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe `scoreEastern` doesn't have the data that you expect all the time? You mentioned that it is dynamic. This snippet appears to work for the use case you posted in your question.

```js
const scoreEastern = [10, 20, 30];

console.log(scoreEastern.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr));
```